# Длина jquery-селекторов

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, длина jquery-селектора влияет на оптимизацию и производительность?
т.е. допустим `$('.js-selector')...`  и
`$('.long .selector .test')...`
влияет ли количество селекторов на производительность?

Answer (score 1):

Оптимизация достаточна важна, но не обязательно указывать все вложения. Более детально можно почитать в документации по ссылке [оптимизация селекторов](https://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)